# autocomplete multiple textboxes based on selected option on dropdown using jquery in php mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a select box that fetches the value from my database, whenever I chose a value from the select box it should show the corresponding data from my database.

For example, If i chose a research, it should show the researcher together with the date started and put it in the two existing textbox.

It is working on my first text box but the second text box is not displaying a value.

Here is my select box that fetches its values from my database;

```
<select id="sel_research">
<option value="0">- Select-</option>
<?php
$sql_research = "SELECT * FROM tblproposals WHERE ProposalStatus = 'Implemented' ";
$research_data = mysqli_query($con,$sql_research);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($research_data) ){
$researchid = $row['id'];
$research_name = $row['TitleOfResearch'];
echo "<option value='".$researchid."' >".$research_name."</option>";
}
        ?>
    </select>
```

Here is my first textbox;

```
<input type="text" id="author"> //it is working here
```

Here is my second textbox;

```
<input type="text" id="datestarted" required>//it is not working here
```

Here is my jquery;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#sel_research").change(function(){
var resid = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
url: 'get-researcher.php',
type: 'post',
data: {res:resid},
dataType: 'json',
success:function(response){
var len = response.length;
$("#author").empty();
for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
var id = response[i]['id'];
var name = response[i]['Researcher'];
var date_imp = response[i]['DateOfImplementation'];

$("#author").val(name);
$("#datestarted").val(date_imp);
                  }
                }
            });
        });

    });
```

Here is my "get-researcher.php"

```
<?php
include "includes/configs.php";
$resid = 0;
if(isset($_POST['res'])){
$resid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['res']);
}

$research_arr = array();
if($resid > 0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblproposals WHERE id='".$resid."' ";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
$res_id = $row['id'];
$name = $row['Researcher'];
$research_arr[] = array("id" => $res_id, "Researcher" => $name);
  }
}

echo json_encode($research_arr);
```

I think i need to use the parseJSON but i got lost on where and how to write it.

Comment: Hi , where is `DateOfImplementation` here `array("id" => $res_id, "Researcher" => $name);..` ?

Comment: @Swati, it is in the tblproposals from my get-researhcer.php, btw I already got the answer just by adding the DateOfImplementation to my array $research_arr[]